# Fragment method does not repeat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, methods, mpandroidchart

I'm creating a line chart with MPandroid chart within a fragment. I've made the line chart and added the code to input custom values. With Logcat tracing, I found that the problem was that the setdata() method in the fragment would only run when the app first starts, not when you return to the fragment screen. This means that the dataset will not update so the chart does not update.

Graph.java (fragment where the chart is displayed)

```
public class Graph extends Fragment {

    public Graph() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private LineChart mChart;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graph, container, false);
        Log.e("create","graph oncreate method reached");
        //initialize chart
        mChart = view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
        //set description
        Description description = new Description();
        description.setText("Blood glucose levels");
        mChart.setDescription(description);
        //set description if no data is available
        mChart.setNoDataText("No Data Available. Add a blood glucose level input to see your graph");
        //enable touch gestures
        mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        //enable scaling and dragging
        mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
        mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);
        //draw background grid
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
        //draw x-axis
        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setEnabled(false);
        // setting position to TOP and INSIDE the chart
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP_INSIDE);
        //  setting text size for our axis label
        xAxis.setTextSize(10f);
        xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        // to draw axis line
        xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

        YAxis yAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        // setting the count of Y-axis label's
        yAxis.setLabelCount(12, false);
        yAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        yAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
        yAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);

        //add upper limit line
        LimitLine upper = new LimitLine(8, "Above target range");
        upper.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#bb2d2d"));
        upper.setLineWidth(3f);
        upper.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        upper.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        upper.setTextSize(9f);
        yAxis.addLimitLine(upper);
        //add lower limit line
        LimitLine lower = new LimitLine(4, "Below target range");
        lower.setLineColor(Color.parseColor("#2c8ec7"));
        lower.setLineWidth(3f);
        lower.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
        lower.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        lower.setTextSize(9f);
        yAxis.addLimitLine(lower);

        yAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);

        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

        // add data
        setData();

        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();



        return view;
    }


    private void setData() {

        ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(new Entry(0, (float) 4.8));
        Log.e("set", "method reached");


        LineDataSet set1;
        if (mChart.getData() != null &&
                mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
            set1 = (LineDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
            set1.setValues(values);
            mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "Blood Glucose Levels");
            set1.setDrawIcons(false);
            set1.setLineWidth(4f);
            set1.setCircleRadius(5f);
            set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
            set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
            set1.setFormLineWidth(1f);
            set1.setFormSize(15.f);
            set1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(set1);
        LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();
//add new input data if bundle isn't null
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            Log.e("if", "if reached");
            float myDataSet = Float.parseFloat(getArguments().getString("INPUT"));
            Log.e("data", "data retrieved");
            float count = 0;
            float mcount = count + 1;
            values.add(new Entry(mcount, myDataSet));

            data.notifyDataChanged();
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mChart.invalidate();
        }

    }
}
```

Tabbed.java (base java class of the fragment)(only relevant code included)

```
public class Tabbed extends AppCompatActivity {

    private InputViewModel mInputViewModel;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);
        androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        InputRoomDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), InputRoomDatabase.class, "input_database")
                .build();

        // Create an instance of the tab layout from the view.
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        // Set the text for each tab.
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.graph));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.table));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.analysis));

        // Set the tabs to fill the entire layout.
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        // Use PagerAdapter to manage page views in fragments.
        // Each page is represented by its own fragment.
        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Setting a listener for clicks.
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new
                TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(
                new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    }
                });
    }
//getting inputs from room and putting them into the view in table
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mInputViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(InputViewModel.class);
        //only add if there is a new input
        if (requestCode == INPUT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //retrieve input from room database
            Input1 input1 = new Input1(data.getStringExtra(input.EXTRA_REPLY));
            //insert the inputs into the view model of the recyclerView
            mInputViewModel.insert(input1);

            //convert the String input1 to a double
            Double d = Double.parseDouble(input1.getValue());

            //send d value to graph.java
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            Log.e("Testing", "Bundle made");
            bundle.putString("INPUT", String.valueOf(d));
            Graph myObj = new Graph();
            myObj.setArguments(bundle);

            }

            //display pop-up if no input is added don't save the input
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    R.string.empty_not_saved,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
        public static final int INPUT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

}
```

Logcat:

```
2019-09-19 11:42:55.074 16844-16844/com.example.mysugartracker E/create: graph oncreate method reached
2019-09-19 11:42:55.076 16844-16844/com.example.mysugartracker E/set: method reached
2019-09-19 11:42:55.121 16844-16844/com.example.mysugartracker E/table: table oncreate method reached
2019-09-19 11:43:00.869 16844-16844/com.example.mysugartracker E/Testing: Bundle made
2019-09-19 11:43:00.871 16844-16844/com.example.mysugartracker E/hello: text sent
```

Just for some context: the data is inputted by the user in a separate activity and then saved in a room database. One of the fragments shows a recyclerview list of the inputs (which works fine) and one other should show the inputs in a line chart. The app runs fine, with no errors or crashes, but the inputs do not show in the chart.

Everything that I've found online says that to refresh the data you just need to call `mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mChart.invalidate();`
which I have done, but the data still doesn't show. From my logcat, I know that the setdata() method doesn't run again when the input is submitted.

I need a way to fix my code so that the data updates dynamically, or some way to ensure that setdata() is called again.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see your call to setData is in onCreateView.
If the view is only created once then it will only be called once.

This will happen if you move on to another activity and then return to this one.
Since the activity was not destroyed, it will not be recreated and it will use the one that already exists.

You need to update the data whenever you show the fragment.
For this use onResume in the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    setData();
}
```

Comment: Hi @theblitz that code worked to rerun the method, thank you so much! However, my log shows that the bundle is being made, yet the if statement in setdata() still won't run, saying the bundle is empty. Would you know how to fix this?